# JOOQ: How to merge with Oracle CLOB column (fitting into a String)?

Tags: java, oracle, jooq

I have a table `ASSETINFO` with the columns `IP` (varchar) and `REPORT` (CLOB) in an Oracle 19 database. The reports have a size of 100 to 100.000 characters and hence fit well into a Java string. I now want to merge incoming reports into the table: If not exists insert, otherwise overwrite the existing one. The `IP` column is my primary key. The problem: Any way I try to implement my usecase, I hit `ORA-01461`. (I currently use JOOQ 3.17)

What I tried:

1. Using JOOQ record API:

```java
final AssetInfoRecord record = ctx.newRecord(ASSET_INFO);
            record.setIpAddr("1.1.1.1");
            record.setReport("*".repeat(60000));
            record.merge();
```

=> ORA-01461

2. Using JOOQ Insert OnConflict style (I think it results in pretty much the same MERGE statement under the hood)

```java
ctx.insertInto(ASSET_INFO)
        .set(ASSET_INFO.IP_ADDR, "1.1.1.1")
        .set(ASSET_INFO.REPORT, "*".repeat(60000))
        .onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
        .set(ASSET_INFO.REPORT, "*".repeat(60000))
        .execute();
```

=> ORA-01461

3. Going for the full MERGE syntax

```java
            Table<Record2<String, String>> toMerge = DSL
                    .values(DSL.row("1.1.1.1", "*".repeat(60000)))
                    .as("toMerge", ASSET_INFO.IP_ADDR.getName(),  ASSET_INFO.REPORT.getName());

            ctx
                    .mergeInto(ASSET_INFO)
                    .using(toMerge)
                    .on(ASSET_INFO.IP_ADDR.eq(toMerge.field(ASSET_INFO.IP_ADDR)))
                    .whenMatchedThenUpdate()
                    .set(ASSET_INFO.REPORT, toMerge.field(ASSET_INFO.REPORT))
                    .whenNotMatchedThenInsert()
                    .set(ASSET_INFO.IP_ADDR, toMerge.field(ASSET_INFO.IP_ADDR))
                    .set(ASSET_INFO.REPORT, toMerge.field(ASSET_INFO.REPORT))
                    .execute();
```

=> ORA-01461

I did the same experiments but added the following forced type in my code generation:

```java
new ForcedType()
                        .withUserType(java.lang.String.class.getName())
                        .withIncludeExpression(".*")
                        .withIncludeTypes(".*CHARACTER\\sLARGE\\sOBJECT.*")
                        .withBinding(org.jooq.impl.ClobBinding.class.getName())
```

and made sure that the ClobBinding is in use for my generated code:

```java
public final TableField<AssetInfoRecord, String> REPORT = createField(DSL.name("REPORT"), SQLDataType.CLOB, this, "", new ClobBinding());
```

The results are the same for all 3 cases.

Is there a nice way in JOOQ with which I can perform a merge in an oracle table for a CLOB column for data that fits into a Java String and hence needs no streams?

Comment: The problem most likely is related to this oracle issue here https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/1620109_1.html but I wonder whether JOOQ can do anything about it.

Comment: I somehow think it is a bug or at least a potential improvement in jOOQ and hence now created a bug ticket with the same content for it here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/15595